# Why doesn't Google capitalize a page title in the search results?

Tags: seo, google, pagerank

In the search results my client's website first sub-listing is not correctly displayed like the titles of other pages, despite using the same structure method in making the pages.

Why does this occur and how could I solve it?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're referring to http://www.andreexpress.be/diensten/ramenwasser/.

Was the page's `<title>` tag ever "ramen en vitrines"?

If you changed the title after Google indexed the page, Google is probably using a cached  version of the page. Give them time to re-index the page and the title will be updated accordingly.

Comment: Also could have been set in `<meta>`, but it's not there currently.

Comment: It could also be from the anchor text of links to that page.

Comment: That was my first thought too... But why would Google use that as page title instead of the one I have given up?